# Como dimensionar as imagens para aplicativos?

Tags: android, ios, imagem, uwp

Estou iniciando um projeto de um aplicativo que pretendo montar que será compatível com UWP + Android + iOS. Além disso, gostaria que ele fosse compatível com celulares, tablets e Desktops.

E é minha primeira vez montando um aplicativo para UWP, então é o que estou estudando mais a API. Olhando a documentação, vi que a Microsoft recomenda sempre manter a proporção de 4x4 nas imagens e que a largura recomendada é 320 para telas pequenas, 720 para telas médias e 1024 para telas grandes. Porém ela não diz nada sobre a altura... com isso... estou com dificuldade de dimensionar as imagens que devo criar.

1) Quais tamanhos de ícones eu deveria criar para atender tantas plataformas? Como fazer? Crio uma imagem para a maior resolução e redimensiono para as menores?

2) Para o Splashscreen, estou pensando em seguir a ideia da Microsoft... colocar uma cor sólida de fundo e uma imagem pequena de loading.

3) Com qual dimensões e densidades de pixels eu deveria trabalhar e considerar as telas? Há algum consenso sobre isso?

Answer (score 0):

Eu acho que você confundiu um pouco as dimensões de tela com dimensões de imagens. 320, 720 e 1024 são os dimensões mínimas dos designs que você deve criar para atender dispositivos pequenos, médios e grandes. Você deve criar um design para cada tamanho? Sim, mas no mesmo arquivo usando a técnica de design responsivo (Responsive Design 101). Como você faz isso? Usando VisualStateManager. Há um exemplo nesse link: [Hello World C# XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn765018.aspx).
Procure mais sobre VisualStateManager e UWP Responsive Design 101. Muito material está disponível em inglês. Espero que não seja um problema para você.